# Ruby - Sending email example code problem

Tags: ruby, email

i´m trying to send an email from ruby but I get an error msg.
 I have this code:

```
    require 'net/smtp'

message = <<MESSAGE_END
From: Private Person <test@test.net>
To: A Test User <test@test.net>
Subject: SMTP e-mail test

This is a test e-mail message.
MESSAGE_END

Net::SMTP.start('smtp.test.net', 25,   'test.com',  'usr', 'pwd', :login) do |smtp| 

  smtp.send_message message, 'test@test.net',     'test@test.net'
end
```

Error msg is: 
C:/Archivos de programa/BitNami Redmine Stack/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:948:
in `check_auth_continue': 502 unimplemented (#5.5.1) (Net::SMTPSyntaxError)
        from C:/Archivos de programa/BitNami Redmine Stack/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net
/smtp.rb:740:in`auth_login'
        from C:/Archivos de programa/BitNami Redmine Stack/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net
/smtp.rb:921:in `critical'

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unless you absolutely need to manually talk SMTP, I'd use either [ActionMailer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Base.html) (from Rails), or maybe [Pony](http://github.com/benprew/pony).  They provide really simple interfaces and deal with the STMP for you.